# Dependency Injection in AsyncValidator in Ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I was planning to implement `AsyncValidator` to create an asynchronous validator but I wasn't able to figure out how to use DI to inject a provider to validate the supplied name against database.

So I ended up using `AsyncValidatorFn` like this:

```
export class CustomValidators {
    static validateName(buyingListProvider: BuyingListProvider): AsyncValidatorFn {
        return (c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> => {
            return buyingListProvider.fetchBuyingListbyName(c.value)
                .then(v => v ? { exists: true } : null);
        };
    }
}
```

And using it this way:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required,
             CustomValidators.validateName(buyingListProvider)]      
});
```

It works! But I am not sure if this is the right way of doing this, and I still wonder how to inject providers into standalone validators.

Any suggestions on how to target that?

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't use static for that. Just export a damn function. You have a complexity budget don't waste it.